# How to remove all XML tags matching a tagName and attribute in python

Tags: python, xml, xsd, lxml, elementtree

I have a large flattened xsd file where each tag has "xs:Something" in front of it.
I have compiled a list of unused types in my flattened XML and I want an automated way to remove the opening, closing tags, and everything in between.

Example XSD:

```
<!--W3C XML Schema generated by XMLSpy v2019 rel. 3 sp1 (x64) (http://www.altova.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" targetNamespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">All Schema files in the OpenTravel Alliance specification are made available according to the terms defined by the OpenTravel License Agreement at http://www.opentravel.org/Specifications/Default.aspx.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleType name="AvailabilityStatusType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Identifies the availability status of an item.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKENS">
            <xs:enumeration value="Open">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory is available for sale.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Close">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory is not available for sale.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="ClosedOnArrival">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory is not available for sale to arriving guests.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="ClosedOnArrivalOnRequest">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory may not be available for sale to arriving guests.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="OnRequest">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory may be available.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="RemoveCloseOnly">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Remove Close restriction while keeping other restrictions in place.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="RatePlanEnum">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Identifies rate plan types.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKENS">
            <xs:enumeration value="Government">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory is available for sale.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Negotiated">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory is not available for sale.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Preferred">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory is not available for sale to arriving guests.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Other_">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory may not be available for sale to arriving guests.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Let's say my unused types list is the following:
myTypes = [RatePlanEnum]

This means I want to remove the entire simpleType name=RatePlanEnum node.

I tried:

```
from lxml import etree 
doc = etree.parse('myfile.xml') 
for elem in doc.findall('.//xs:simpleType'): 
    parent = elem.getparent() 
    if(elem.attrib.get('name') = 'RatePlanEnum'): 
        parent.remove(elem)
```

How do I do this programmatically and spit out the xml after all the modifications?

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: I tried using lxml:


```from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('myfile.xml')
for elem in doc.findall('.//xs:simpleType'):
    parent = elem.getparent()
    if(elem.attrib.get('name') = 'RatePlanEnum'):
         parent.remove(elem)
```

Comment: you should add code in question - it will be more readable and everyone will see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file uses namespace `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` and you have to use `{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}` instead of `xs:` in `findall()`

```
 doc.findall('.//{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}simpleType'):
```

Doc: [lxml - Namespaces](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces)

---

Full example:

```
from lxml import etree 

data = '''<!--W3C XML Schema generated by XMLSpy v2019 rel. 3 sp1 (x64) (http://www.altova.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" targetNamespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">All Schema files in the OpenTravel Alliance specification are made available according to the terms defined by the OpenTravel License Agreement at http://www.opentravel.org/Specifications/Default.aspx.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleType name="AvailabilityStatusType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Identifies the availability status of an item.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKENS">
            <xs:enumeration value="Open">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory is available for sale.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Close">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory is not available for sale.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="ClosedOnArrival">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory is not available for sale to arriving guests.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="ClosedOnArrivalOnRequest">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory may not be available for sale to arriving guests.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="OnRequest">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory may be available.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="RemoveCloseOnly">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Remove Close restriction while keeping other restrictions in place.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="RatePlanEnum">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Identifies rate plan types.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKENS">
            <xs:enumeration value="Government">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory is available for sale.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Negotiated">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory is not available for sale.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Preferred">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory is not available for sale to arriving guests.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="Other_">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inventory may not be available for sale to arriving guests.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>'''

doc = etree.fromstring(data)

for elem in doc.findall('.//{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}simpleType'):
    parent = elem.getparent()
    if elem.attrib.get('name') == 'RatePlanEnum':
        parent.remove(elem)

print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `lxml`, you can apply an XSLT-1.0 stylesheet which ignores the element that should be removed being passed a parameter to the stylesheet. The rest of the file is copied by the *identity template* and the unnecessary spaces are removed by `xsl:strip-space`.

Here the parameter is passed by `remov`(=`RatePlanEnum`):

```
remov = ET.XSLT.strparam('RatePlanEnum')
```

The XSLT-1.0 stylesheet (`remove.xslt`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:param name="toRemove" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:simpleType">
        <xsl:if test="@name != $toRemove">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Python code to call this stylesheet could be:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

# Parse XML and XSLT
dom = ET.parse(input_xml_filename)
xslt = ET.parse('remove.xslt')
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
# Set the parameter which specifies the element to be removed
remov = ET.XSLT.strparam('RatePlanEnum')
result = transform(dom, toRemove=remov)

# Print the result
print(ET.tostring(result, pretty_print=True))
```