# How to alter 2 subelements of xml file in python by their tag parameter using ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml file like this, I want to alter the 2 sub-elements.

I tried like below.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

file_name = 'manifest.mpd'
tree = ET.parse(file_name)
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root:
    for subelem in elem:
        a = subelem.attrib
        if a['mimeType'] == 'audio/mp4':
            if subelem.get('lang') == 'bg':
                source_elem = subelem
                break

for elem in root:
    for subelem in elem:
        d = subelem.attrib
        if d['mimeType'] == 'audio/mp4':
            if (subelem.get('lang') == 'tr'):
                subelem = source_elem

tree.write('output.mpd')
```

Below is my xml file.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" ?>
      <MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011" minBufferTime="PT4.80S" mediaPresentationDuration="PT44M19.080S" type="static">
        <Period>
          <AdaptationSet mimeType="video/mp4" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1" maxWidth="1920" maxHeight="1080">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="4800" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1"/>
            <Representation id="video/avc1/1" codecs="avc1.64001E" width="640" height="360" scanType="progressive" frameRate="25" bandwidth="798779"/>
            <Representation id="video/avc1/2" codecs="avc1.640028" width="1920" height="1080" scanType="progressive" frameRate="25" bandwidth="4107000"/>
            <Representation id="video/avc1/3" codecs="avc1.64001E" width="848" height="480" scanType="progressive" frameRate="25" bandwidth="1498236"/>
            <Representation id="video/avc1/4" codecs="avc1.64001F" width="1280" height="720" scanType="progressive" frameRate="25" bandwidth="2497736"/>
          </AdaptationSet>
          <AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" lang="en">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="2000" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1"/>
            <Representation id="audio/en/mp4a.40.2" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="131529" audioSamplingRate="48000">
              <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:mpegB:cicp:ChannelConfiguration" value="2"/>
            </Representation>
          </AdaptationSet>
          <AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" lang="tr">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="4800" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1"/>
            <Representation id="audio/tr/mp4a.40.2" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="127472" audioSamplingRate="44100">
              <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:mpegB:cicp:ChannelConfiguration" value="2"/>
            </Representation>
          </AdaptationSet>
          <AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" lang="ru">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="2000" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1"/>
            <Representation id="audio/ru/mp4a.40.2" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="129917" audioSamplingRate="48000">
              <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:mpegB:cicp:ChannelConfiguration" value="2"/>
            </Representation>
          </AdaptationSet>
          <AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" lang="bg">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="2000" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1"/>
            <Representation id="audio/bg/mp4a.40.2" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="135019" audioSamplingRate="48000">
              <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:mpegB:cicp:ChannelConfiguration" value="2"/>
            </Representation>
          </AdaptationSet>
          <AdaptationSet mimeType="text/vtt" contentType="text" lang="en">
            <Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:role:2011" value="subtitle"/>
            <Representation id="subtitles/en" bandwidth="141">
              <BaseURL>subtitles/en/TDCS00187_SPY001285-00001ENG.vtt</BaseURL>
            </Representation>
          </AdaptationSet>
          <AdaptationSet mimeType="text/vtt" contentType="text" lang="sr">
            <Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:role:2011" value="subtitle"/>
            <Representation id="subtitles/sr" bandwidth="130">
              <BaseURL>subtitles/sr/TDCS00187_SPY001285-00001SRB.vtt</BaseURL>
            </Representation>
          </AdaptationSet>
          <AdaptationSet mimeType="text/vtt" contentType="text" lang="hr">
            <Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:role:2011" value="subtitle"/>
            <Representation id="subtitles/hr" bandwidth="132">
              <BaseURL>subtitles/hr/TDCS00187_SPY001285-00001CRO.vtt</BaseURL>
            </Representation>
          </AdaptationSet>
          <AdaptationSet mimeType="text/vtt" contentType="text" lang="sq">
            <Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:role:2011" value="subtitle"/>
            <Representation id="subtitles/sq" bandwidth="139">
              <BaseURL>subtitles/sq/TDCS00187_SPY001285-00001ALB.vtt</BaseURL>
            </Representation>
          </AdaptationSet>
        </Period>
      </MPD>
```

I want to alter the below complete node(first audio type node)

```
<AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" lang="en">
  <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="2000" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1"/>
  <Representation id="audio/en/mp4a.40.2" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="131529" audioSamplingRate="48000">
    <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:mpegB:cicp:ChannelConfiguration" value="2"/>
  </Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
```

with it's any other node(audio type node)

```
<AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" lang="tr">
  <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="4800" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1"/>
  <Representation id="audio/tr/mp4a.40.2" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="127472" audioSamplingRate="44100">
    <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:mpegB:cicp:ChannelConfiguration" value="2"/>
  </Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
```

And save this content into a new xml file.

Is there any methods to replace nodes?

I tried by searching the nodes with their 'lang' parameter, but I couldn't get it.

To be clearly Any audio node has to be replaced(shifted/altered) with audio node.

e.g.
I want the node which is having the lang="bg" to be shifted with the node which is having the lang="en".

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: you want to change the order of the first two audio nodes?

Comment: @zx485 To be precisely Yes. Again I want to shift the 1st audio node to be replaced 3rd node, and 3rd to be replaced with 1st nodes.

Comment: @zx485  I just added few lines to my question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to order the languages in a custom (speak: different) order, you can use an XSLT-1.0 stylesheet that can be processed by any XSLT-1.0 capable processor (like `xsltproc`, `Saxon`, `Xalan` and others).

It could look like this (using the `lang` tags as criteria for ordering):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:mpeg="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mpeg:AdaptationSet[@mimeType='audio/mp4'][1]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="../mpeg:AdaptationSet[@mimeType='audio/mp4'][@lang='bg']" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="../mpeg:AdaptationSet[@mimeType='audio/mp4'][@lang='en']" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="../mpeg:AdaptationSet[@mimeType='audio/mp4'][@lang='ru']" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="../mpeg:AdaptationSet[@mimeType='audio/mp4'][@lang='tr']" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mpeg:AdaptationSet[@mimeType='audio/mp4'][position() > 1]" />
      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

```
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011" minBufferTime="PT4.80S" mediaPresentationDuration="PT44M19.080S" type="static">
    <Period>
        <AdaptationSet mimeType="video/mp4" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1" maxWidth="1920" maxHeight="1080">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="4800" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1"/>
            <Representation id="video/avc1/1" codecs="avc1.64001E" width="640" height="360" scanType="progressive" frameRate="25" bandwidth="798779"/>
            <Representation id="video/avc1/2" codecs="avc1.640028" width="1920" height="1080" scanType="progressive" frameRate="25" bandwidth="4107000"/>
            <Representation id="video/avc1/3" codecs="avc1.64001E" width="848" height="480" scanType="progressive" frameRate="25" bandwidth="1498236"/>
            <Representation id="video/avc1/4" codecs="avc1.64001F" width="1280" height="720" scanType="progressive" frameRate="25" bandwidth="2497736"/>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" lang="bg">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="2000" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1"/>
            <Representation id="audio/bg/mp4a.40.2" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="135019" audioSamplingRate="48000">
                <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:mpegB:cicp:ChannelConfiguration" value="2"/>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" lang="en">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="2000" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1"/>
            <Representation id="audio/en/mp4a.40.2" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="131529" audioSamplingRate="48000">
                <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:mpegB:cicp:ChannelConfiguration" value="2"/>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" lang="ru">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="2000" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1"/>
            <Representation id="audio/ru/mp4a.40.2" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="129917" audioSamplingRate="48000">
                <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:mpegB:cicp:ChannelConfiguration" value="2"/>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" lang="tr">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="4800" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1"/>
            <Representation id="audio/tr/mp4a.40.2" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="127472" audioSamplingRate="44100">
                <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:mpegB:cicp:ChannelConfiguration" value="2"/>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        
        
        
        <AdaptationSet mimeType="text/vtt" contentType="text" lang="en">
            <Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:role:2011" value="subtitle"/>
            <Representation id="subtitles/en" bandwidth="141">
                <BaseURL>subtitles/en/TDCS00187_SPY001285-00001ENG.vtt</BaseURL>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet mimeType="text/vtt" contentType="text" lang="sr">
            <Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:role:2011" value="subtitle"/>
            <Representation id="subtitles/sr" bandwidth="130">
                <BaseURL>subtitles/sr/TDCS00187_SPY001285-00001SRB.vtt</BaseURL>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet mimeType="text/vtt" contentType="text" lang="hr">
            <Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:role:2011" value="subtitle"/>
            <Representation id="subtitles/hr" bandwidth="132">
                <BaseURL>subtitles/hr/TDCS00187_SPY001285-00001CRO.vtt</BaseURL>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet mimeType="text/vtt" contentType="text" lang="sq">
            <Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:role:2011" value="subtitle"/>
            <Representation id="subtitles/sq" bandwidth="139">
                <BaseURL>subtitles/sq/TDCS00187_SPY001285-00001ALB.vtt</BaseURL>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>apply-templates
```

You can call this XSLT from Python like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58175507/1305969). Pay attention to the fact that other languages than the ones being copied are ignored without notice.

Comment: Hi, Sorry if I mislead you. I thought you would use xslt python module. I simply need a pythonic kind of solution only.

Comment: Well, ok then. But you could use XSLT transformations with `lxml` as described in the linked answer. XSLT is just the most comfortable and clearest way to handle XML situations.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you having a look at  The ElementTree XML API in Python: [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

I've used it in the past to parse really large XML files (over 1gb) and it was one of the fastest solutions that I've found.